# NGINX Header and Body Filter Modules

Tags: module, filter, nginx

I've been coding an NGINX filter module that can read/write cookies for incoming requests.  If a particular cookie isn't set correctly (i.e. authentication cookie), it will set the outgoing header status to the appropriate error code.  This works fine per the directions of [Evan Miller's tutorial](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#filters-header).  The next part I'm trying to get working (and haven't thus far) is having the body filter be invoked so I can insert/replace body response text when error responses are encountered.  I again followed [Evan Miller's tutorial](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#filters-body) on body filters, and I cannot for the life of me get this working.  Here's my setup:

```
static ngx_http_output_header_filter_pt ngx_http_next_header_filter;
static ngx_http_output_body_filter_pt ngx_http_next_body_filter;
...
...


static ngx_http_module_t ngx_http_source_cookie_module_ctx = {
    NULL,                             /* preconfiguration */
    ngx_http_source_cookie_init,             /* postconfiguration */

    NULL,                             /* create main configuration */
    NULL,                             /* init main configuration */

    NULL,                             /* create server configuration */
    NULL,                             /* merge server configuration */

    ngx_http_source_cookie_create_loc_conf,  /* create location configuration */
    ngx_http_source_cookie_merge_loc_conf    /* merge location configuration */
};

ngx_module_t ngx_http_source_cookie_module = {
    NGX_MODULE_V1,
    &ngx_http_source_cookie_module_ctx,      /* module context */
    ngx_http_source_cookie_commands,         /* module directives */
    NGX_HTTP_MODULE,                  /* module type */
    NULL,                             /* init master */
    NULL,                             /* init module */
    NULL,                             /* init process */
    NULL,                             /* init thread */
    NULL,                             /* exit thread */
    NULL,                             /* exit process */
    NULL,                             /* exit master */
    NGX_MODULE_V1_PADDING
};
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_source_cookie_header_filter(ngx_http_request_t *r)
{
   // this gets invoked
   ...
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_body_filter(ngx_http_request_t *r, ngx_chain_t *in)
{
   // this never get invoked
   ...
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_source_cookie_init(ngx_conf_t *cf)
{
    // registering of my filters

    ngx_http_next_header_filter = ngx_http_top_header_filter;
    ngx_http_top_header_filter = ngx_http_source_cookie_header_filter;

    ngx_http_next_body_filter = ngx_http_top_body_filter;
    ngx_http_top_body_filter = ngx_http_body_filter;

    return NGX_OK;
}
```

This is my basic setup, and as far as I can tell, it's spot on all the examples/tutorials I've come across.  I'm wondering if there's something different altogether I need to enable... like a NGINX config option, NGINX ./configure compile option, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the NGINX version you are using? What ./configure parameters did you use? I had a similar problem trying to run a body filter module with the stable version, then I tried with the dev version (1.3.5) and it worked (dont know why).

Answer (score 0):

I note that Evan doesnt fix http content length in `ngx_http_<module_name>_header_filter()`.

If I dont add http content length(`r->headers_out.content_length_n`), the inserted text to the end of request will not be output from nginx-1.2.7 stable.

Also you can see [footer filter module](https://github.com/alibaba/nginx-http-footer-filter).