# Nginx - Allow requests from IP range with no header set

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use nginx behind a Compute Engine http load balancer. I would like to allow Health Check requests to come through a port unauthorized and all other requests to be authorized with basic auth.

The Health Check requests come from IP block: 130.211.0.0/22. If I see requests coming from this IP block with no X-forwarded-for header, then it is a health check from the load balancer.

I'm confused on how to set this up with nginx.

Comment: Top result from https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nginx+restrict+by+ip  which is http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/ appears to have an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Nginx header modules? Googling around I found these:

- [HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule)
- [Headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#example)

There's also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103514/nginx-header-and-body-filter-modules).

Alternative. In the past I worked with a software ([RT](https://www.bestpractical.com/rt/)), which had thought of this possibility in the software itself, providing a subdirectory for unauthorized access (/noauth/). Maybe your software might have the same, and you could configure GCE health check to point to something like `/noauth/mycheck.html`.

Please remember that headers can be easily forged, so an attacker who knows your vulnerability could access your server without auth.